# FactoryGirl Rspec ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I'm new to rails and am trying to give TDD a try.

I have a user model that has an admin attribute that is set to nil by default and a request model.

Here's a test that I have for my request controller

```
it "should grant access to 'destroy'" do
        req = Factory(:request, :user => @user)
        delete :destroy, :id => req.id
        response.should be_successful
end
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm guessing this is because my views have links that only show up if the user owns the link or if they are an admin. So, I'm doing conditional testing on the admin attribute. Do I need to set the admin attribute to false?

How do I deal with this?

Comment: I'd say that @user is tested if he is an admin so it looks like @user is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake. I tried to call user.admin in my controller when the user was nil. I created a helper method to check if user was nil before checking the admin field.

```
def admin?(user)
  if not user.nil?
    return user.admin
  end
  return false
end
```