# factory girl create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**company_factory.rb**

```
Factory.define :company, :class => Company do |c|
      c.company_name 'companyname'
      c.address 'companyadress'
      c.phone '012323232'
      c.company_prize_ratio 10
      c.partner_prize_ratio 10
      c.bank_name 'bankname'
      c.iban 'iban'
      c.sequence(:company_password ) {|n| "company_password_#{n}"}
    end
```

**partner_factory.rb**

```
Factory.define :partner, :class => Partner do |i|
  i.association :company, :factory => :company
  i.email 'partner@mail.com'
  i.password 'partnerpassword'
  i.partner_name 'partnername'
  i.partner_type :nil
end
```

These are my factory files.When I run  `@company = Factory(:company)` this command in pry,it creates company factory but when I run `@partner = Factory(:partner)` I encounter this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `user_type' for #<Partner:0x007fa56d339860>
```

But there is no user_type attribute in partner model.Do you know why I got this error?

Comment: What's the line number, and more specifically can you mark the line associated line in your example code? I can see that there is no `user_type` attribute, so this makes me think that it may be broken elsewhere in your code - maybe in a place you're not showing in your question.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error` implies you have to check your view. Looks like you call `user_type` on a Partner's instance there.

Comment: @jdoe, but FactoryGirl has nothing related with ActionView, hasn't it?

Comment: @ted I decided we're dealing with a testing error. Now I see the question has **rspec** tag, so it could be an error on rendering a view.

Comment: Your factories have no problem . You have some problem in controller or view of Partner when you accidently called user_type on partner object . see this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6040448/1970061 he was also facing same issue.